# AngularJS: Route displaying blank page

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps

I have a route/view that is displaying a blank page. I am pretty sure it was working the way I have it right now a few days ago which leads me to think it is a problem with my Google Maps API key, but there are no errors or warnings so I think it has to do with my routing setup. But I have another view set up exactly the same way and that one does work...

Broken view: http://alainwebdesign.ca/pl2/#/49.2/-122.66

Working view: http://alainwebdesign.ca/pl2/#/getLocation

Controller (I commented out the.config for Google Map API because I have a script reference in my view searchRadius.html) :

```
(function (window, ng) {
    ng.module('app', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps', 'ui.router'])



  .config(function ($stateProvider) { //had: , $stateChangeError included in the function parameters, but that caused error 
      $stateProvider.state('searchRadius', {
          url: '/:lat/:lon',
          templateUrl: 'searchRadius.html', //changed from  index to searchRadius.html
          controller: 'MapsCtrl',
      });
  })


  ////ALREADY HAVE GOOGLE MAPS KEY ON searchRadius.html
    .config(['uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider', function (GoogleMapApi) {
      GoogleMapApi.configure({
          key: 'AIzaSyC_XEbbw3sNm4XlLAgqMJTggeHLDUdV-pY',
          v: '3',
          libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
      });
  } ])

.controller('MapsCtrl', ['$scope', "uiGmapLogger", "uiGmapGoogleMapApi", "$interval", "$state", "$stateParams",
  function ($scope, $log, GoogleMapApi, $interval, $state, $stateParams) {
      $log.currentLevel = $log.LEVELS.debug;
      var center = { latitude: parseFloat($stateParams.lat), longitude: parseFloat($stateParams.lon) };
      alert(JSON.stringify(center));
      Object.freeze(center); //caused TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property ('latitude') ...

      console.log($stateParams);

      $scope.map = {
          center: center,
          pan: false,
          zoom: 16,
          refresh: false,
          events: {},
          bounds: {}
      };

      $scope.map.circle = {
          id: 1,
          center: center,
          radius: 500, //(current time - date lost)*km/hour
          stroke: {
              color: '#08B21F',
              weight: 2,
              opacity: 1
          },

          fill: {
              color: '#08B21F',
              opacity: 0.5
          },
          geodesic: false, // optional: defaults to false
          draggable: false, // optional: defaults to false
          clickable: true, // optional: defaults to true
          editable: false, // optional: defaults to false
          visible: true, // optional: defaults to true
          events: {
              dblclick: function () {
                  $log.debug("circle dblclick");
              },
              radius_changed: function (gObject) {
                  var radius = gObject.getRadius();
                  $log.debug("circle radius radius_changed " + radius);
              }
          }
      }

      //Increase Radius:
      $interval(function(){
            $scope.map.circle.radius += 30; //dynamic var
      }, 1000); //end of interval function


  } ]); //end of controller

})(window, angular);
```

searchRadius.html:

```
<div style="height: 100%"> <!--took out: ng-if="map.center !== undefined"-->
    <ui-gmap-google-map 
                        center='map.center'
                        zoom='map.zoom'
                        draggable='map.draggable'
                        dragging='map.dragging'
                        refresh='map.refresh'
                        options='map.options'
                        events='map.events'
                        pan='map.pan'>


        <ui-gmap-circle 
                        center='map.circle.center'
                        radius='map.circle.radius'
                        fill='map.circle.fill'
                        stroke='map.circle.stroke'
                        clickable='map.circle.clickable'
                        draggable='map.circle.draggable'
                        editable='map.circle.editable'
                        visible='map.circle.visible'
                        events='map.circle.events'>

        </ui-gmap-circle>


    </ui-gmap-google-map>
<script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC_XEbbw3sNm4XlLAgqMJTggeHLDUdV-pY'></script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the 2 files into 1 file and initialize the $stateProvider in a single line.

Comment: You mean is the code I have posted above for my controller the same that I'm using currently for searchRadius.html? Yes it is

Comment: I am trying to use getLoc.js for my getlocation.html view, and searchRaidus.js for my searchRadius.html but maybe I have it set up wrong?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what path you're talking about. But I use routing to link the MapsCtrl Controller to searchRadius.html here: '          templateUrl: 'searchRadius.html',
          controller: 'MapsCtrl',' so the paths should be ok shouldn't they?

Comment: Later on I guess I will have to use nested states but for right now I don't think it is nested because it is just the root and then 2 parameters (:lat/:lon)

Comment: WAIT I just saw what you meant by both are using getLoc.js! When I look at the sources in developer tools the only js that shows up when I'm at my broken view is getLoc.js, but it should be searchRadius.js so I think you are right about that. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: yes I was telling that, you can fix it in your HTML code. Just change the JS  code names in HTML.

Comment: I already have both getLoc.js and searchRadius.js linked in index.html so I'm not sure how I would fix it. Would I have to change the JS code names in index.html or searchRadius.html?

Comment: Mmm, now i see.

Comment: I tried ''/searchRadius/:lat/:lon'' but it didn't work

Comment: It's weird because sometimes searchRadius.js does show up under sources but other times it doesn't. Either way the page is still blank tho

Comment: Check this link http://alainwebdesign.ca/pl2/#/searchRadius/49.22/-122.66

Comment: Hope this note helps. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#using-parameters-without-specifying-them-in-state-urls

Comment: Can you add alert("some message") in the MapsCtrl? so that we can debug if it is really loaded, although not listed in Chrome dev tools.

Comment: I already have an alert that shows JSON.stringify(center) a few lines below the start of the controller, so they must not be linked

Comment: I haven't used routing much before so I think i probably made a mistake to do with that. Does it matter that I have 2 routes (getlocation.html and searchRadius.html) that can be accessed directly after the root (ie. http://alainwebdesign.ca/pl2/#/49.2/-122.66 and http://alainwebdesign.ca/pl2/#/getLocation ? It seems like there's some overlap there and it's a bit amiguous as to which page is supposed to be loaded between getlocation.html and searchRadius.html

Comment: Can you combine the router JS codes in one? or change the order of loading in HTML? I think the getLoc.js is overwriting. Just change the order of JS files. Let's see that.

Comment: You're right that fixed it! Just one problem, now http://alainwebdesign.ca/pl2/#/getLocation is broken haha. Maybe you're right and I should combine them into one 'controllers.js' file, I've seen some other apps do that. It shouldn't impact the app/mess it up in any way should it?

Comment: I see you have changed the order. See that now the searchRadius is working and the other is not working. What a tricky hehe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125310/discussion-between-enkuushka-and-thomas).